# How to automatically shut down tablet after it auto-powers on?

Tags: automation, power-on, shutdown

Currently my tablet on Android 4.0.4 (rooted) sometimes switches on by accident, which I don't want. (I'm cycling through Africa and sometimes power connections are minimal.) I need a way to shutdown the tablet after starting up. So something like:

1. Start on boot
2. After X (say, 10) minutes, prompt me to continue with a "*Yes*" button (in case I use it)
3. If I select "*No*", shuts down and completely powers off the tablet.

I tried several apps but cannot find a solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ermm... what if "Yes" button is accidentally pressed while cycling? Perhaps a timeout of 1 minute is sufficient...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (paid; 7 day free trial) and its [Scenes](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/scenes.html) to achieve the goal.

Example:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

## Instructions

(**Note:** root access is needed to shutdown the device.)

1. Go to Tasker → Scenes and create a scene named *Auto off*.
2. Per your taste, set the size of the scene.

   You can add text using Text element. The *Yes* and *No* in the images are also text elements but you can opt for button elements too.
3. Similarly, create a separate scene for *Yes* and *No* options named *Yes* and *No*.

   While you've not asked for confirmation, I've considered *Andrew T.*'s [point](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127480/how-to-automatically-shut-down-tablet-after-it-auto-powers-on#comment158000_127480) legit and genuine, hence, separate confirmation for *Yes* and *No* selection would do good.
4. I'm giving a broad idea here.

   - For each element of scene, under Tap there is an option to execute an action when the element is tapped once.
   - Show scene and Destroy scene options are available under Scenes action category.
   - For any Show scene, set Display As: Overlay Blocking and uncheck Show Exit button -- this would force you to choose an option in a scene and avoids the scene getting closed by a hardware button, such as Back button.
   - Wherever you want to show the timer, mention `%Scount`.
   - *Auto off* scene,

     - for the *Yes* element, destroy *Auto off* scene and show *Yes* scene
     - for the *No* element, destroy *Auto off* scene and show *Yes* scene
   - *Yes* scene,

     - for *Yo man!* element, destroy *Yes* scene and do Task → Stop → *Auto power off*
     - for *Shutdown now* element, select System → Reboot → Type: Shutdown
   - *No* scene,

     - for *Just do it!* element, select System → Reboot → Type: Shutdown
     - for *Hell no!!* element, destroy *No* scene and do Task → Stop → *Auto power off*
5. Profile, task and actions:

   1. Profile: Event → System → Device Boot
   2. Task: (Name: *Auto power off*): (Actions):

      1. Task → Wait → set Wait as the time period after which you want to seek user intervention to continue or shutdown
      2. Scene → Show Scene → select your first scene (*Auto off*)
      3. Variables → Variable Set → Name: `%Scount`, To: set 60 or maximum number of seconds for auto shutdown timer
      4. Task → Wait → 1 minute
      5. Variables → Variable Subtract → Name: `%Scount`, Value: 1
      6. Task → GoTo:

         - Type: Action Number
         - Number: 4
         - If `%Scount` `>` `0`
      7. System → Reboot → Type: Shutdown

---

**Supplementary info:**

- `%Scount` is your custom global [variable](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/variables.html) which should be equal to the maximum value of auto shutdown timer, such as 60 for 1 minute or 60 seconds.
- In the task *Auto power off*, the variable gets set to maximum value of timer after the first X minutes wait is over and first scene is shown. This is what starts the timer.
- For timer to work, Tasker waits for one second, then subtracts value 1  from the current value of `%Scount`, decides to wait for one second  and do the subtraction again, if the variable's value is not zero, and once the values reaches zero device executes the shutdown action. (I learned about the timer from the post by *nooblikeyou* [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/240ugl/til_how_to_make_a_simple_notification_with/).)
- In the *Yes* and *No* scene, the task *Auto power off* is supposed to be stopped wherever you choose to continue using the device, else, once the timer completes the device will auto shutdown.
- The solution would work even if the screen is off.

Comment: I've tested my solution on Android 4.2.1 and 5.0.2, if it matters.